# Export SQL Server data into a specific sheet in Excel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to replicate a defunct homegrown program that I don't have access to the source code.  Basically I need to read in a SQL file (here denoted as querySqlAddresses[i]), execute it and dump the result into a specific sheet in a file that I have open.

I'm finding a lot of dead end things, but I think there may be promise in this, I am just not sure HOW to drop the "results" or even what the "results" variable is so I can target it.  Does this even make sense?

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(querySqlAddresses[i]);
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

Comment: Hint: a SQL statement with results is commonly called a "query".  You are calling `ExecuteNonQuery`.  Try looking for another method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So this code looks like it's opening a text file that should contain an SQL script, connecting to an SQL server, then executing the contents of the script.  "ExecuteNonQuery" does not return results.  You probably want to look at "ExecuteReader" to get a read-only result set back from your script.  (And you might want to be certain that the script that you're executing is selecting data and not, oh, say dropping your databases or anything like that.)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found another way of doing it using OleDB connections and passing the User Name, Password and Table space into the connection string.

```
        string connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" + tableSpace + ";User Id=" + userName + ";Password=" + password + ";";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter Dadpt = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(readText, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Dadpt.Fill(ds);
        cnn.Close();
```